# How to change opacity of a div on button click using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, opacity

I am trying to add a script to my HTML file that changes the opacity of a div when a button is clicked.

[This is the HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkQOQ.png)

[This is the CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUheK.png)

[This is my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orPWV.png)

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is the div that is currently set to 0 opacity, will be change to 1 opacity on the click of the button. Currently this is not working, and I am relatively new to incorporating JS in and HTML file. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser's dev tools console? And what does 'not working' mean - that the element never shows or that it never disappears?

Comment: getElementsClassname - not a function? You maymean getElementsByClassName but that will return a collection not a single element and does not require the . in the classname. Look up querySelector and use MDN to read up about any JS function you are trying to use.

Comment: I have multiple buttons in the same class, that was just one of the blocks of code.

Comment: After fixing what A Haworth mentioned, this is my error: script.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'opacity')
    at changeOpacity (script.js:10:30)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (aboutme.html:27:73)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using JavaScript embedded in HTML. Make sure you're using an event listener that listens for the click of your button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>About Me</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="opacity: 0;">About Me</h1>
    <button>
      Show
    </button>
    <script>
      var button = document.querySelector('button');
      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
        h1.style.opacity = 1;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```